# COVID-19 data analysis with Python from Github CSV

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, github, python-requests

This link contains CSV files for daily reports of COVID-19.

https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/tree/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports

What is the best solution to get all the csv files in a dataframe?

I tried the code bellow from other questions but it doesnt work.

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

files = Path('https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/tree/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports')

csv_only = files.rglob('*.csv')

combo = [pd.read_csv(f)
         .assign(f.stem)
         .fillna(0)
         for f in csv_only]

one_df = pd.concat(combo,ignore_index=True)

one_df = one_df.drop_duplicates('date')
print(one_df)
```

How could i fit requests to read all the files?

Comment: should we call it the _[con](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=con)vid19_ ?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `requests` module to get the names of all the `.csv` present, which would eliminate the need to run `glob`:

```
import requests
url = "https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/tree/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports"
csv_only  = [i.split("=")[1][1:-1] for i in requests.get(url).text.split(" ") if '.csv' in i and 'title' in i]
```

Comment: And how should i pass that to a DF?

Comment: `pd.read_csv(url.replace("github","raw.githubusercontent")+"/"+csv_only[i])` should load the file. Rest you already seem to have figured out!

Comment: Got `NameError: name 'i' is not defined` on `csv_only[i])`

Comment: I mean you already had your `for f in csv_only` part, then replace `csv_only[i]` with `f` : (within the for loop, so that you can concat later)

Comment: `[pd.read_csv(url.replace("github","raw.githubusercontent")+"/"+f)  for f in csv_only]`

Comment: Was missing `.replace("/tree/","/")` to remove the `/tree` from URL. It worked now! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`pathlib` only works with filesystems so this won't do. `csv_only` will be an empty generator since there is no such location on your disk. You need to fetch the data from github with actual http requests. I did something for some personal stuff some time ago, you can [have a look](https://gist.github.com/axegon/9eb654e129681655a953cf70e1482963) and modify it accordingly(uses the github API so you'll need to get one).